# Share data between 2 Angular micro frontend apps that reside in different repository

Tags: micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular15

I have 2 angular micro frontend apps residing in different repository

**Angular shell app -- Repository 1**

**Angular Micro frontend app1 -- Repository 2**

**Angular Micro frontend app2 -- Repository 3**

Is there any way to share data between shell app and micro frontend apps

Iam using **@angular-architects/module-federation** for creating micro frontend apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using **new** **CustomEvent()** we can send messages and using **fromEvent()** we can receive the messages

Comment: I think it should be another way